# Fat-Free Framework, Wix, and X-Frame-Options

Tags: php, .htaccess, fat-free-framework, velo

I have built a widget using the Fat-Free Framework for a client that should make their life easier, but they also requested that their website is created using Wix.  I thought it would be easy to embed this F3 site within the Wix site using their embedding plugins (there are built-in and plug-in versions).

The problem is that regardless of the answers I have received so far on SO and other sites, I still get an X-Frame-Options is set to SAMEORIGIN error.  I have tried the following:

- `header_remove()` php command
- `header('X-Frame-Options: GOFORIT')` php command (`GOFORIT` is for anything but `SAMEORIGIN` and `DENY`)
- adding `&output=embed` to the link (this didn't work with F3)
- adding the following htaccess code:

  `Header always append X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN
  Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "http://editor.wix.com"
  Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "http://www.wix.com"`

I am afraid that the Wix embed plug-in will be a bit limited and I won't be able to change much on that end. Any ideas what to try next?  Is there some configuration for F3 that will help this problem or am I using the PHP code wrong?  Does anything need to be configured on the Wix site? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't look into my .htaccess file.  There was the line `Header append X-FRAME-OPTIONS "SAMEORIGIN"` in there along with some allows for Wix.  Simply removing the `append` line allowed it to be embed.

Answer (score 1):

Try to set the XFRAME option for the framework:

```
$f3->set('XFRAME','GOFORIT');
```

https://github.com/bcosca/fatfree-core/blob/master/base.php#L2153

Comment: Thanks a lot!  So it looks like it is working on my local server but when I put it on the Bluehost server, it is `'GOFORIT'` and `'SAMEORIGIN'`.  I suppose I need to remove `'SAMEORIGIN'` somehow, any ideas?  Should I set it to null first or something?

Comment: try to set it empty: $f3->set('XFRAME','');

Comment: `$f3->set('XFRAME, '');` doesn't work, neither does `$f3->set('XFRAME', NULL);`, I still get `SAMEORIGIN` on my Bluehost server